# If $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $c, d\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $a\leq c<d\leq b$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c, d]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if my proof is correct and if it could be improved somehow, thanks.

"Suppose $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable. Prove that if $c, d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\leq c<d\leq b$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c, d]$."

Proof. (NOTE: edited according to the answer by SomeCallMeTim below)

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by hypothesis, there must be a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P,[a,b])-L(f,P,[a,b])<\varepsilon$.

Now, if this partition $P$ contains $c,d$ fine, if it doesn't consider the partition $P'$ which is the partition $P$ with the points $c,d$ added to it: then $U(f,P',[a,b])\leq U(f,P,[a,b])$ and $L(f,P,[a,b])\leq L(f,P',[a,b])$ so $U(f,P',[a,b])-L(f,P',[a,b])<\varepsilon$ and since$^1$ $$U(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])-L(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])\leq U(f,P',[a,b])-L(f,P',[a,b])$$

we obtain $$U(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])-L(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])<\varepsilon$$.

We have shown that given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P'_{[c,d]}$ of $[c,d]$ such that $U(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])-L(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])<\varepsilon$ so $f$ is integrable on $[c,d]$, as desired. $\square$

---

$^1$ since $U(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])-L(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])=\sum_{j=j_c}^{j_d}(x_j-x_{j-1})( \sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f-\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f)$ $\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})(\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f-\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f)=U(f,P',[a,b])-L(f,P',[a,b]);\ \ \  1\leq j_c,j_d\leq n$

$^2$ since $U(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])-L(f,P'_{[c,d]},[c,d])\leq U(f,[c,d])-L(f,[c,d])$

Comment: Your proof seems correct. But it is much easier to use the (Lebesgue) integrability criterion (for Riemann integrals)

Comment: @GReyes Thanks for your feedback. If you would write your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it (after a few days to let other users comment on the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and well detailed. I wouldn't talk about Lebesgue integrability criterion, as this seems like a very classical approach.
However, one way to make your argument cleaner is to do a direct proof instead of by contradiction. In short, you assume it is not integrable on [c,d], and then prove that it IS integrable on [c,d], thereby the contradiction - but it is nicer just to prove integrability directly.
What I more precisely mean is, let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary, and proceed basically as in your proof, and remove the final line.

Comment: This is more like a comment.

Comment: @ArcticChar I see why you may think that, but the question was quite literally asking whether his proof is correct and if there are any possible improvements. I believe I answered that question.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Thank you for your answer; I have incorporated your idea of proving integrability directly into my proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another comment (or answer depending on your point of view).  The technique you are using can be used to handle a different version of the same theorem.  This one is more general,arguably more informative, and does not require anything other than what you already developed.   While it looks completely different to your proof it is essentially what you have done but expressed in a different language.

The argument, while it doesn't use anything other than your computations, is a bit simpler since we can work just with $U(f,P)$, not $L(f,P)$.

We  express it for the upper/lower Darboux integrals.

$$\overline{\int_a^b} f = \inf_P\  U(f,P), \ \  \underline{\int_a^b} f= \sup_P \ L(f,P)$$

where $P$ is an arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$.

**Theorem**.  *Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded function and let $a<c<b$.  Then
$$\overline{\int_a^b} f= \overline{\int_a^c}f   +\overline{\int_c^b}f \ 
\text{   and    } \  \underline{\int_a^b }f= \underline{\int_a^c}f +\underline{\int_c^b}f.$$
If, moreover, $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then it is also integrable on both $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ with
$$ {\int_a^b f}= {\int_a^c f} + {\int_c^b f}.$$*

From this theorem it follows easily that $f$ is integrable on every subinterval.  If $a<c<d<b$ and $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then it is integrable on $[a,d]$.  But then it is integrable on both $[a,c]$ and $[c,d]$.

You aleady have the tools to prove this.

Step 1.  Show $\overline{\int_a^b} f\leq \overline{\int_a^c}f   +\overline{\int_c^b}f$.

Step 2.  Show $\overline{\int_a^b} f\geq \overline{\int_a^c}f   +\overline{\int_c^b}f$.

Step 3.  Conclude that $\overline{\int_a^b} f = \overline{\int_a^c}f   +\overline{\int_c^b}f$

Step 4.  Claim (without proof) that  $\underline{\int_a^b} f = \underline{\int_a^c}f   +\underline{\int_c^b}f$ is similar.  *[Dangerous sometimes: there are notorious cases where an "upper" argument does not transfer trivially to a "lower" argument.]*

Step 5.  Show that if  $\overline{\int_a^b} f =\underline{\int_a^b} f$  then
$\overline{\int_a^c} f -\underline{\int_a^c} f = - \left[\overline{\int_c^b} f -\underline{\int_c^b} f\right] $.

*[To use this step remember that an upper integral is always greater or equal to a lower integral.]*

Step 6.  Conclude that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ it is also integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ with the required identity.